# Cannot import name 'SCHEME_KEYS' from 'pip._internal.models.scheme' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

I want to install flask in my virtual environment . I used "pip install flask" commmand ,but I got this error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\news_bot\myvenv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import (
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.scheme import SCHEME_KEYS, Scheme
ImportError: cannot import name 'SCHEME_KEYS' from 'pip._internal.models.scheme' (c:\users\user\desktop\news_bot\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\models\scheme.py)
```

I had updated pip and after updation I am getting this error.

OS:Windows

Python version:3.8.5

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Anaconda, try:

```
conda install pip [--force-reinstall]
```

This worked for me. Other suggestion could be

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

but this did not work for me, since pip tries to upgrade itself but runs into the same error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The below steps will reset pip3 and should fix the issue.

1. rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools*
2. rm -rf  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip*
3. python3 -m ensurepip

Answer (score 0):

I found location of pip folders on my end was in django_project/venv/bin
There was pip, pip3, pip3.8 & pip3.10
I deleted them running rm -r pip;rm -r pip3;rm -r pip3.8;rm -r pip3.10;
Then reinstalled an earlier version of pip with command: easy_install pip==19.2.3

Answer (score -1):

You need to save `get-pip.py` file in the `anaconda3\Scripts` directory or `anaconda3\envs\[env_name]\Scripts` if you are working on virtual environment.

Then, you need to `cd` to this directory:

```
cd anaconda3\Scripts
```

After that run:

```
python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1  # or 21.0.1
```